# How to resolve ParseError while migrating to Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo

While installing my module (open erp 7) in odoo8, I am getting this error. Please help me out.

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Invalid predicate" while parsing /home/anipr/Desktop/odoo-8.0/openerp  /addons/transtech_module/configuration_panel_view.xml:166, near
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_user_tree_view_extend">
        <field name="name">res.user.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data><xpath expr="//field[@name='date'" position="replace">
        </xpath>
            <field name="lang" position="after">
                <field name="role"/>
                <field name="contact_num"/>
                <field name="joining_date"/>
            </field>
        </data></field>
   </record>
```

Comment: put full error log for better understanding...

Answer (score 3):

Your string hasn't closed the `[`.

```
expr="//field[@name='date'"
```

is bad, because it's missing the final `]`

```
expr="//field[@name='date']"
```

is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `xpath` expression, add `]` after `date`:

```
//field[@name='date']
```